# ListView with Drop-downlist & check box

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am developing an asp.net web application in which I have Listview with drop-down & check-box option.

All the items checked needs to inserted into SQL Table.

However , before inserting to database , there needs to validation on drop-down to make sure drop-down has selected value (Selected index should not be 0 ) if checkbox is checked

Kindly Help me for the same
Below is my aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="myListView" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="myListView_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="myListView_ItemCommand"   >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblmemberid" Text='<%# Bind("memberid") %>'>></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblName" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'>></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblAge" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>'>></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlStatus"   AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" CommandName="Select" OnCommand="myListView_ItemCommand" AutoPostBack="true" ID="chkSelect" />
            <br />

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

Below is my code

```
public void bindData()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Subh_Vivah;Data Source=.;password=adarkar";
            //con.Open();
            string memberid = Request.QueryString["memberid"];
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 10  Name , memberid , age FROM Member_Details  ";
            SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ada.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {

                myListView.DataSource = ds;
                myListView.DataBind();
            }

        }

        protected void myListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> status = new List<string>();
            status.Add("SELECT");
            status.Add("YES");
            status.Add("NO");

            DropDownList ddl = e.Item.FindControl("ddlStatus") as DropDownList;
            ddl.DataSource = status;
            ddl.DataBind();
            ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged);

        }

        protected void ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)myListView.FindControl("chkSelect");



            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
            if (ddl.SelectedValue == "SELECT")
            {
                chk.Checked = false;
                chk.Enabled = false; 
            }


        }
```

Comment: so what kind of problem your are facing?

Comment: You can disable the dropdown by default and enable it when the checkbox is checked also add a required field validator setting the initial value to 0. This might do the work for you.

Comment: I think it should be other way round...  By Defaut dropdown should be with SELECT value... If dropdown value is other than SELECT, checkbox needs to be enabled